# Synchronize the events in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, synchronization

I'm trying to load data from a jsp page. This data is used in furthur operations.
here is my code where questionBankSize and questionBank are global variables

```
public function initialiseQuestionBank():void
{
    questionBankSize = 20;

loadQuestion();

trace(questionBankSize+"");

}
```

and here is my code for loading data from jsp page

```
private function loadQuestion() {


        var url:String = "http://localhost:8084/JspPages/JsonJsp.jsp";
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        requestVars.topic_id = 1;   
        request.data = requestVars;
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler, false, 1, true);
        try {
    urlLoader.load(request);
} catch (e:Error) {
    trace(e);
}
```

}

```
private function loaderCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {

        var ldr:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
        var responseVars:String = ldr.data;
        var arr:Array = (JSON.decode(responseVars) as Array);
        trace(arr[i]['clue']);
        questionBankSize = arr.length;
        questionBank = new Vector.<String>(questionBankSize);
        for (var i:int = 0; i < questionBankSize; i++ ) {
            questionBank[i] = arr[i]['clue'] + "$" + arr[i]['word'];
        }
        trace(questionBank[0]);
        load = 1;
```

}

trace statement in initialiseQuestionBank() function is executing before the trace statements in event handler. How can I complete the execution of event handler first then execute the next statements?

Comment: You cannot, as the load request is asynchronous by design. So just don't.

Comment: So is there any other way to acheive the same functionality?

Comment: Yes, you relocate the code that traces the updated question bank length into `loaderCompleteHandler`.

Comment: Actually  initialiseQuestionBank() is a constructor that is used by another .as file which is also using the question bank.

Comment: Then you need to rework your code flow, you cannot make question bank instantly available if you are loading it from elsewhere.

Comment: You can check the answer here : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695696](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695696), hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the question bank loader into an object which extends Event.

That way you will be able to dispatch your own custom event.

In your constructor you will call the loadQuestion method passing it a callback function that will execute whatever code you are intending to run after the questionbank is loaded. That way you will run your events concurrently and have your code called just after you signal that the load has ended.

Comment: can you give an example please?